# listagg output formatting

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Im trying to list each BookId with all its authors on the same line using listagg.

I would like it to look like this;

```
BOOKID AUNAMES

1101: Dilbert Emerson Sartre.
```

But when I execute the command the output is poorly formatted

```
select BOOKID,
listagg (AUNAME,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY auname)
AUNAMES
FROM BOOK_AUTHOR
group by bookid;
```

And looks like this:

```
BOOKID
----------
AUNAMES
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1101
Dilbert,Emerson,Sartre
```

Im using SQL plus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing stops you to make your query a sub-query and select again:

```
SELECT BOOKID || ':' || AUNAMES FROM 
(
 select BOOKID,
 listagg (AUNAME,' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY auname)
 AUNAMES
 FROM BOOK_AUTHOR
 group by bookid
) A
```

If you want to use a space as a delimiter use it in the listagg function

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to concatenate the two columns.

One way is to use `||`:

```
select BOOKID || ': ' || listagg (AUNAME,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY auname)
FROM BOOK_AUTHOR
group by bookid;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23522/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use the format command.
Example:
If your column length is 500 and line size is just 80, then the next column value will not appear on the same line.

In your case use the format like this:

```
 select BOOKID,
 listagg (AUNAME,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY auname)
 AUNAMES Format A25
 FROM BOOK_AUTHOR
 group by bookid;
```

All the formatting stuff in Oracle can be searched through the keyword: "SQLPlus Formatting". One good link is below (Not covers everything):
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b12170/ch7.htm